# How to make "view" read vimrc?

Tags: vimrc

`view` is the readonly mode of `vim`. I would like `view` to read the exact same `.vimrc` file for its initialization as `vim` already does.

`view` does not seem to read `~/.vimrc` by default (I checked by adding `echo "hello, world"` at the bottom). Using `view -u ~/.vimrc` does not work for me either. Reading `:help initialization` it seems that there are special files for **e**vim and **e**view, but not for `view`.

Unsurprisingly, `vim -R` reads `.vimrc` files. How do I make `view` do the same?

### Version info

#### vim

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun 14 2019 11:41:55)
Included patches: 1-160, 399, 402-403, 1099
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim74"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__linux__ -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE  -Wl,-z,relro  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -lnsl  -lselinux  -lncurses -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE  -fstack-protector  -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
```

#### view

```
$ view !$
view --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun 14 2019 11:42:11)
Included patches: 1-160, 399, 402-403, 1099
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             -farsi           -mouse_sgr       -tag_old_static
-arabic          -file_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
-autocmd         -find_in_path    -mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    -float           -mouse_xterm     +terminfo
-browse          -folding         +multi_byte      -termresponse
+builtin_terms   -footer          -multi_lang      -textobjects
-byte_offset     +fork()          -mzscheme        -title
-cindent         -gettext         -netbeans_intg   -toolbar
-clientserver    -hangul_input    -path_extra      -user_commands
-clipboard       +iconv           -perl            -vertsplit
-cmdline_compl   -insert_expand   -persistent_undo -virtualedit
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        -printer         +visual
-cmdline_info    -keymap          -profile         -visualextra
-comments        -langmap         -python          -viminfo
-conceal         -libcall         -python3         -vreplace
-cryptv          -linebreak       -quickfix        +wildignore
-cscope          -lispindent      -reltime         -wildmenu
-cursorbind      -listcmds        -rightleft       +windows
-cursorshape     -localmap        -ruby            +writebackup
-dialog          -lua             -scrollbind      -X11
-diff            -menu            -signs           -xfontset
-digraphs        -mksession       -smartindent     -xim
-dnd             -modify_fname    -sniff           -xsmp
-ebcdic          -mouse           -startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
-emacs_tags      -mouse_dec       -statusline      -xterm_save
-eval            -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xpm
-ex_extra        -mouse_jsbterm   -syntax
-extra_search    -mouse_netterm   -tag_binary
   system vimrc file: "/etc/virc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim74"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__linux__ -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-z,relro  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm  -lselinux -lncurses -lacl -lattr -ldl
```

Comment: Is you `view` actually from Vim, and not something else (say, heirloom vi)? What do `view --version` and `vim --version` report?

Comment: @muru both report `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4` at the top. However, view reports `Small version without GUI` compared to vim's `Huge version without GUI`. Nothing in the lists of included features (which are obviously different) suggest that initialization would be different. Both commands print similar list of `vimrc` files with `view` reporting one more than `vim`: `system vimrc file: "/etc/virc"`. I'll add both outputs to the question.

Comment: You should consider that `view` *is* reading your `.vimrc` file but you're not seeing the effects of it. For example, if you expected to see syntax highlighting, that's disabled on the "small" version of Vim in RHEL/CentOS 7. Use `:scriptnames` to check which Vim script files were read by Vim (or `view`), that might tell you more or confirm whether `.vimrc` is being read or not...

Comment: if your `view` binary is provided by Vim, it should read your `:vimrc`. Check the output of `:scriptnames` to make sure.

Comment: Btw `:scriptnames` won't work since it's built without `+eval`. It's possible your `:echo` is not showing because of redraw (see `:help :echo-redraw`). Try using `:echomsg` instead, then check `:messages` to confirm the message from `.vimrc` is being logged.

Comment: If the vim is without `+eval`, then `echomsg()` won't work as well. @andrybak, you might need to link `view` to your `vim` binary (the huge version). Or use `update-alternatives`, which is for Debian, so use the correct alternative for Redhat/CentOS

Comment: @filbranden, "Use :scriptnames to check which Vim script files were read by Vim (or view), that might tell you more". `vim` prints quite large list of files. And as you rightly pointed out `view` does nothing for `:scriptnames`. Looks like I will indeed need to `alias view='vim -R'` or something like that. I don't have sudo access on this machine, so won't be able to change `/bin/view`.

P.S. I think filbranden's and Christian's comments can be turned into an acceptable answer.

Comment: @andrybak check `which -a view`—you may have more than one, and the old/less-featureful one is taking precedence. You could update your `PATH` in this case

Answer (score 1):

My view `--version` showed that it's using `$HOME/.virc`
So I linked `$HOME/.vimrc` to `$HOME/.virc`

```
$ cd
$ ln -s .vimrc .virc
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!